# Go, how to import package from github and build without go get

Tags: github, go, package

I need to import external package from github “`github.com/xy/packageX`” to `MyProject/src/myProjcet.go`. So I added import “`github.com/xy/packageX`” to `myProject.go`. If I run go build, I get:

```
myProject.go:9:2: import “github.com/xy/packageX”: cannot find package
```

So I have to run `go get`, and then `go build`.
Is there a way, how it can be built without using of `go get`? Or should I download it to `MyProject/pkg` and added this link to `myProject.go`? I am on Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why don't you want to use 'go get'?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add your go project  dependency to the global GOPATH, you can vendor it. (go 1.6+ recommended: see "[Vendor Directories](https://tip.golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Vendor_Directories)")

Go to the package which uses that import, and add it as a submodule in a vendor sub-folder.

```
cd GOPATH/src/myproject/mypackage
git submodule add -- https://github.com/<user>/<repo> vendor/github.com/<user>/<repo>
cd vendor/github.com/<user>/<repo>
go install
cd ../../../..
go install
```

Note: that repo might have itself other dependencies, that you would need to add in a similar fashion (in the same vendor folder)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is up to the repository, such as github,
When the initial "go install" will be "go get" even as packageX.